# Heat equation for solar radiation on a wall

Tags: civil-engineering, thermodynamics, heat-transfer

I'm trying to model the effects of solar radiation on a (thick) concrete wall. My assumptions are followings:

- The wall behaves as an half continuum with parameters $k = 0.8 W/Km$, $\rho=2500 kg/m^3$, $c_p=880J/kg K$
- Solar radiation is simulated as an heat flux on the wall surface $\dot{q}(0,t) = 650 W/m^2$
- There is an exchange of heat between wall and surrounding air,  modeled using an heat transfer coefficient $h=15W/m^2K$ and considering air temperature as constant with $\vartheta_\text{air}$

Now I should solve the heat equation 
$$ u_{,t} -\alpha u_{,xx}=0$$

Under following IC and BC:
$$\begin{cases} u(x,0) = \vartheta_0 \\ 650+ h(\vartheta_\text{air}-u(0,t))= -k u_{,x}(0,t) \end{cases}$$

I tried to solve this PDE using Mathematica, but gave me a nonsensical result. Taking $h=0$ however leads to good results. So I'm quite sure the error lies in the consideration of the flux between wall and air (boundary condition), but don't see it.

---

EDIT: Here is the code I used in mathematica.

```
k=0.8; c=880;  rho=1950; a=k/(c*rho); h=15; theta_air=0;

heqn=D[u[x,t],t] == a*D[u[x,t],{x,2}];
ic1=u[x,0] == 0;
bc1 = h*(theta_air-u[0,t])+650 == -k*Derivative[1,0][u][0,t]
theta_0 = 20;

sol=DSolveValue[{heqn,ic1,bc1},u[x,t],{x,t}][[1,1,1]]

f[x_,t_]=sol;
theta_0+f[0.,7200]
theta_0+f[0.1,7200]
```

which gives:

```
15.3649+0.i
2.6153+0.i
```

Again, this PDE gives the correct result assuming $h=0$ (no heat exchange between wall and air). This result was checked with the solution of an exercise found on a book.

Comment: Why aren't you considering heat transfer into the infinitely deep wall?   As a lesser note,  you need to account for radiative heat loss via the BlackBody equations, not just conductive to the atmosphere.

Comment: Do you mean the term Q/(c*rho)? I have no heat sources in the wall. Sure, I can in a later step consider radiative heat loss. I'm actually trying to create a benchmark problem for some FE calculations and I add increasingly complexity. The problem with my current PDE is that I really get unmeaningful results (negative temperature at t=0 on the surface)

Comment: the problem as you have posed it has no specified domain x.  (how do you put infiniity into your system of equations? ) Maybe post up the code (or if folks think that's off topic post it on mathematica.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @agentp What do you mean? The obtained solution should be valid only for x>0 (and indeed that's the case if h=0). I now posted the code. It should be still on topic, since the main question remains the IC and BC and not the code itself.

Comment: you are missing a semicolon here: `a=k/(c*rho) h=15`  What is `theta_0`?

Comment: I assumed you were solving numerically re: earlier comment about  x domain.

Comment: @agentp oh, yeah. I just copied/pasted the code quickly and made only one line out of two. theta_0 is the real initial temperature. To make it simpler (at least analytically) I set initial temp.=0 everywhere (instead of 20), I solve the PDE and I add up 20 everywhere.

Comment: Ok, I solved this analytically. Tomorrow I can add an answer for future purposes. The problem then lies in my mathematica implementation. I'll then post a new question on mathematica SE.

Comment: `theta_0` should be somewhere in your system of equations. eg `h*(theta_air-u[0,t]-theta_0)`. (Really i don't see what you gained by subtracting it off in the first place)

Comment: Everything is at theta_0 at t=0 (both the wall and air). Basically I just avoid to solve a particular solution and to backtransform it (since I'm using Laplace transforms to solve it). In the end it's just a matter of definition of the zero of my temperature scale. Hence, I can get my solution for °C minus 20 and in the end add 20 again to obtain °C. As much as I could use Kelvin and transform to Celsius